# How can you print the type of a haskell expression in main?

Tags: haskell

I'm writing the code in a .hs file, so I want to print the type of an expression in main. Suppose I have the following code:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    ...
    let l = fmap getFirstElem listOfURL
    print (:type l)) --print the type of l
```

Is there a equivalent to :type in GHCi Prelude?

Comment: If you only want to do that for better understanding your program, you will find it much easier to, rather than following the path suggested by the duplicate, take advantage of [partial type signatures](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#partial-type-signatures). Replacing your print line with `print (l :: _)` will lead to a compile error that will tell you the type of `l`. That works equally well both when compiling to an executable and when loading the source file in GHCi.

Comment: Meta comment: if this is a XY question in the way I suspect it to be (see my comment above), I think it is worth reopening it.